# VBA: Creating series in a chart

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create two different series but if I run the macro the second series keeps overwriting the first one unfortunately. So that at the end, I only have the second series in my chart. Can anyone help?

```
     With ChtObj
    'Series LTU
        Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries    
        With Ser
        .Name = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
        .XValues = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
        .Values = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
        End With
    'Series LTA
        With Ser
        .Name = "LTA_" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 1)
        .XValues = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal) & "," & Dataws.Range(Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 14), Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 22)).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
        .Values = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal) & "," & Dataws.Range(Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 42), Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 50)).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
        End With
    End With
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using the same `Ser`, so this is replaced.

```
With ChtObj

    Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    With Ser
    .Name = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
    .XValues = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
    .Values = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
    End With
'Series LTA

    Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With Ser
    .Name = "LTA_" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 1)
    .XValues = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal) & "," & Dataws.Range(Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 14), Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 22)).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
    .Values = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal) & "," & Dataws.Range(Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 42), Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 50)).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
    End With
End With
```

Try defining a new series again or use a different name for Series2.

Comment: Nice, beat me to it